# Do JAVA apps have to run on JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Do JAVA apps have to run on JSP? Are there other ways the app can be interpreted on the client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clients (assuming you mean browsers like Firefox, IE etc.,) can understand HTML and Javascript only. Your JSP code will be executed on server and respective HTML code will be sent to browsers.

There are lot of alternatives like JSF, HTML etc., are available. I would suggest reading this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html).

Answer (score 2):

JSP is a technology that runs on the server side and produces a response that will typically be viewed in a web browser.  There are many other ways to do the same, including Java servlets, JSF, etc.

Java can run on the client side either as an application (i.e. the user downloads a file and runs it locally), or as an applet (which runs in the web browser).